# Border of Boostrap cards

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi I want to use Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta Cards.

First the class "card-block" not works for me. Only if I use the class "card-body" it looks like the examples.

How can I remove the double border between my cards? Every card has a border of 1px - between them there is a border of 2px, I want only 1px. Is there a simple possibility?

This is my code:

```
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Can you post CSS? Ideally add a demo too, thanks

Comment: [`.card-block` is not a class used by Bootstrap 4 beta](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [border utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/)...

https://www.codeply.com/go/tukHrs1GLz

```
   <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border-right-0">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border-right-0">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border-right-0">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also note, `card-block` changed to `card-body` from [alpha 6 to beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32)

It would be better to put the cards *inside* the columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I but "border-right-0" - this only works when 4 cards in the row. Smaller screens only show 2 cards - then a border is missing.

I tried to but the cards into the cols - but than the hight of the cards is different, if one is higher than the others.

Comment: The question of how to remove the border has been answered. If the grid and cards is not working for your scenario, consider a different option like the [card groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-groups)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 has a [border classes](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/borders/) that you can add to your cards. Here's your code with the `border-right-0` class added to all of the cards except the last one.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border-right-0">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border-right-0">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3 border-right-0">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card-img-top"><img src="pic.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">my text</div>
            <div class="card-footer">my footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/xLyPZG

Comment: How was this response not helpful?